# complete and repeat one dataframe along another one

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

How do you combine 2 dataframes so that one is repeated over and over and combined for every line of the other dataframe, for example :

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[2,4]])
print(d1)
   0  1
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

and

```
d2 = pd.DataFrame([['A','D'],['B','E'],['C','F']])
print(d2)
   0  1
0  A  D
1  B  E
2  C  F
```

combining in :

```
d3 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,'A','D'],[1,3,'B','E'],[1,3,'C','F'],[2,4,'A','D'],[2,4,'B','E'],[2,4,'C','F']])
print(d3)
   0  1  2  3
0  1  3  A  D
1  1  3  B  E
2  1  3  C  F
3  2  4  A  D
4  2  4  B  E
5  2  4  C  F
```

I can loop over d1 and concat, but is there any implemented functionnality already doing this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are searching for is a cross-join.

You can use the following code to get your answer, you will just need to clean up the column naming

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[2,4]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['A','D'],['B','E'],['C','F']])
df1.merge(df2, how = 'cross')
```

Comment: Thanks ! That is exactly what I was looking for !
However, I am also working on pandas 0.24.0 (for some reason) and it does not work with this older version.
I still believe this is the best answer, but for the record, in my situation https://stackoverflow.com/a/75460662/18018014
and https://stackoverflow.com/a/75461205/18018014
also works with older version of pandas.

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this works for your solution. Create a key column with value of 1 in both dataframes and join with that key and then drop it.

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[2,4]])
print(d1)
d2 = pd.DataFrame([['A','D'],['B','E'],['C','F']])
print(d2)
d1['key'] = 1
d2['key'] = 1
d1.merge(d2, on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, it has the benefits to work with old version of pandas ! Although I believe ArchAngelPwn's solution is overall better.

Comment: Yes, ArchAngelPwn's solution works better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution using [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`df.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```py
d2.columns = ['2', '3']
d3 = pd.merge(d1.assign(key=1), d2.assign(key=1), on='key', suffixes=('', '')).drop('key', axis=1)
print(d3)
```

---

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  3  A  D
1  1  3  B  E
2  1  3  C  F
3  2  4  A  D
4  2  4  B  E
5  2  4  C  F
```